# How do I call a validator method to validate the input that's coming through gateway before passing to the parallel flows in scatterer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I'm using Spring-integration in my project and the pattern used is scatter-gather. Here three parallel processes are being carried out. Before any of the parallel process starts I want to call a method which returns nothing but that will validate the Request body that is being sent via gateway to the main flow.

Below is the code - -

//Config file

```
@Configuration
    public class IntegrationConfiguration {
      @Autowired LionsServiceImpl lionsService;
    
      long dbId = new SequenceGenerator().nextId();
  //   Main flow
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.split()
            .log()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .convert(LoanProvisionRequest.class)
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.releaseLockBeforeSend(true))
            .log()
            .aggregate(a -> a.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getMessages))
            .channel("output-flow");
  }
  //   flow1
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message -> {
                  try {
                    lionService.saveLionRequest(
                        (LionRequest) message.getPayload(), String.valueOf(dbId));
                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
                });
  }

  //   flow2
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message ->
                    lionService.getData(
                        (LionRequest) message.getPayload(), SourceSystem.PROVISION))
            .log();
  }

  //  flow3
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow3() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message ->
                    lionService.prepareCDRequest(
                        (LionRequest) message));
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor("output-flow", outputExecutor()).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor outputExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(4);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    return pool;
  }
}
```

Here before passing LionRequest to the parallel flows in the scatter block I want to call a method probably just before/after calling split() to validate that request and if the request is not as per my standard then my method will throw exception and the main flow also should stop there. Where and How should I call that method. That method returns nothing and accept LionRequest as input parameter.

Gateway

```
 @MessagingGateway
    public interface LionGateway {
    
      @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input", replyChannel = "output-flow")
      List<?> echo(LionRequest lionRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have that `flow.split()`. So, to validate whatever is an input, you just need to insert one more endpoint before. Something like this:

```
flow
   .<LionRequest>handle((p, h) -> validate(p))
   .split()
```

for example.

Then you go to the Spring Validation API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validator. Inject a `Validator` into your `@Configuration` and call it something like this:

```
LionRequest validate(LionRequest value) {
    BeanPropertyBindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(value, "request");
    ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(this.validator, value, errors);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        throw new BindException(errors);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Or you do something similar in the dedicated component, and use its method call in that `handle()` lambda.

We definitely need to revise an out-of-the-box validation support: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4068 ...

**UPDATE**

If you have some `void validate(LionRequest)` method, you can delegate into it like this:

```
 .<LionRequest>handle((p, h) -> {
           validate(p);
           return p;
        })
```

The point is that you need to continue the flow somehow, but `void` return is a signal to stop the flow. So, to validate and go on when no errors, you need to delegate and return the request payload since it is valid.

Comment: Hi @Artem, if I'm using the handle method as you've suggested it's showing compile error as -> Bad return type in lambda expression: void cannot be converted to object. Kindly help.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry, must be `return value`. Just copied it from some my other code blindly. Fixing my answer.

Comment: actually I have my own validate method which doesn't return anything. It's just validate and throw exception if find any bad request. So kindly suggest how do I add that void method into here.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hi Artem, is there a way that if I use overloaded method and in the same way I can send two arguments?

Comment: I think that fully different question and overloaded is only going to work from the current message context: you can use only a `payload` and headers for those arguments. So, you have to have a respective mapping for their expectations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

Comment: Can u please elaborate a bit? if u want I'll ask a different question on this

Comment: Yes, please, a new SO question. This one about calling a validation from the integration flow an d we are good with that I believe.

Comment: Yes Artem. Good with that.